# Contact form doesn't send if there is a space in name

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I am reviewing a contact form for a website, but right now it doesn't want to send if in the sender name (like "John Smith") have space, it only sends if it's just a single word ("John"). Where could the problem be, I don't know anything about .php, but I am finding my way around.

EDIT: Ok, here is the code

```
<?php


function sendemail($toname, $toemail, $fromname, $fromemail, $subject, $message, $type = "plain", $cc = "", $bcc = "") {

    require_once "class.phpmailer.php";

    $mail = new PHPMailer();


        $mail->IsMAIL();




    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->From = $fromemail;
    $mail->FromName = $fromname;
    $mail->AddAddress($toemail, $toname);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($fromemail, $fromname);
    if ($cc) { 
        $cc = explode(", ", $cc);
        foreach ($cc as $ccaddress) {
            $mail->AddCC($ccaddress);
        }
    }
    if ($bcc) {
        $bcc = explode(", ", $bcc);
        foreach ($bcc as $bccaddress) {
            $mail->AddBCC($bccaddress);
        }
    }
    if ($type == "plain") {
        $mail->IsHTML(false);
    } else {
        $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $message;

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $mail->ErrorInfo;
        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
        $mail->ClearReplyTos();
        return false;
    } else {
        $mail->ClearAllRecipients(); 
        $mail->ClearReplyTos();
        return true;
    }

}
}


function descript($text, $striptags = true) {
// Convert problematic ascii characters to their true values
    $search = array("40","41","58","65","66","67","68","69","70",
        "71","72","73","74","75","76","77","78","79","80","81",
        "82","83","84","85","86","87","88","89","90","97","98",
        "99","100","101","102","103","104","105","106","107",
        "108","109","110","111","112","113","114","115","116",
        "117","118","119","120","121","122"
        );
    $replace = array("(",")",":","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h",
        "i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u",
        "v","w","x","y","z","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h",
        "i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u",
        "v","w","x","y","z"
        );
    $entities = count($search);
    for ($i=0; $i < $entities; $i++) {
        $text = preg_replace("#(&\#)(0*".$search[$i]."+);*#si", $replace[$i], $text);
    }
    $text = preg_replace('#(&\#x)([0-9A-F]+);*#si', "", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+[/\"\'\s])(onmouseover|onmousedown|onmouseup|onmouseout|onmousemove|ondblclick|onfocus|onload|xmlns)[^>]*>#iU', ">", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)=([\`\'\"]*)script:#iU', '$1=$2nojscript...', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)=([\`\'\"]*)javascript:#iU', '$1=$2nojavascript...', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)=([\'\"]*)vbscript:#iU', '$1=$2novbscript...', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+)style=([\`\'\"]*).*expression\([^>]*>#iU', "$1>", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+)style=([\`\'\"]*).*behaviour\([^>]*>#iU', "$1>", $text);
    if ($striptags) {
        do {
            $thistext = $text;
            $text = preg_replace('#</*(applet|meta|xml|blink|link|style|script|embed|object|iframe|frame|frameset|ilayer|layer|bgsound|title|base)[^>]*>#i', "", $text);
        } while ($thistext != $text);
    }
    return $text;
}

$name=0;
$telefon=0;
$sender=0;
$syobshtenie=0;
$ename=0;
$etelefon=0;
$esender=0;
$esyobshtenie=0;

if($_POST['name']){
$name = "Запитване от ".$_POST['name'];
}
else { $name=1; $ename=1; }


if($_POST['sender']){
$sender = $_POST['sender'];
if(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $sender))
{
$sender="Email";
}
}

else { $sender=1; $esender=1; }

if($_POST['telefon']){
$telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
}


if($_POST['zapitvane']){
$zapitvane = $_POST['zapitvane'];
$syobshtenie = "<p>Запитване от ".$_POST['name']."
<br />Email: ".$sender."
<br />Телефон: ".$telefon."</p>".$zapitvane;
}

    else { $syobshtenie=1; $esyobshtenie=1; }


if($name=="Име"){ $ename=1; }
if($telefon=="Телефон"){ $etelefon=1; }
if($sender=="Email"){ $esender=1; }
if($syobshtenie=="Моля, въведете съобщение до нас"){ $esyobshtenie=1; }


if($ename==0 && $esender==0 && $esyobshtenie==0 && $etelefon==0){

sendemail("VillaDes", "info@konsumator.com", "", $sender, $name, $syobshtenie, "", "", "");

echo '
<div class="active-error"" style="margin-top:5px;">Съобщението Ви беше изпратено.<br /><br />Приятен ден!</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("contact").reset();
</script>';
}


else {
echo '
<div class="border-15"></div><div class="active-error"><b>Моля, въведете:</b></div><div class="border-8"></div>';

if($ename==1) { echo '<div class="active-error">Име</div><div class="border-8"></div>'; }
if($esender==1) { echo '<div class="active-error">Е-поща</div><div class="border-8"></div>'; }
if($etelefon==1) { echo '<div class="active-error">Телефон</div><div class="border-8"></div>'; }
if($esyobshtenie==1) { echo '<div class="active-error">Запитване</div>'; }  
}

                echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#close-email").click(function () { $("#mailresult").hide("fast"); } );
                });
                </script>';

?>
```

Comment: post code even if its not english, it's not the words we need to see anyway.

Comment: To me this code doesn't make much sense in relation to your question. You mention the e-mail not being sent if you have a space in your sender's name. This code does not pass a name into the sender variable (I'm assuming that this is `$fromname`) at all. Is this the original code or have you been trying some things?

Comment: yes, this is the original code, though I am not the one who wrote it. I am to find the problem. So the problem is, that if you enter a single name, like John, the admin or whoever it is, receives the email. But if you have space in the name, the website tells you the mail is sent, but the Admin receives nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you post you call:

```
sendemail("VillaDes", "info@konsumator.com", "", $sender, $name, $syobshtenie, "", "", "");
```

Your sendemail function accepts:

```
sendemail($toname, $toemail, $fromname, $fromemail, $subject, $message
```

So `$fromname` will be used as the subject of your e-mail and formname will be empty. 
class.phpmailer.php should handle subjects with spaces, so i don't think this will be the problem.
When you use `$name` as `$fromemail` spaces will be a problem maybe. (name without spaces can be a local mailbox??).

Beside all this you don't need the class.phpmailer.php to send your email.
Use the default mail function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
$headers = 'From: "'.$fromemail.'" <'.$fromname.'>' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: "'.$fromname.'" <'.$fromemail.'>' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail('"VillaDes" <info@konsumator.com>',$syobshtenie, "", $headers);
```

Comment: so what should I change in order to send it even with spaces? I don't know anything about php

Comment: replace the line `sendemail($toname...` with the code for the php mail function. Now you can send even with spaces in name. If you don't have knowledge of php consider to use something like http://green-beast.com/