# Contact form doesn't send if there is a space in name PT 2

Tags: php, forms, contacts

Ok, so here is my last question [Contact form doesn't send if there is a space in name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124918/contact-form-doesnt-send-if-there-is-a-space-in-name), I have accepted an answer, but now there's a new problem (kinda). I am making a new thread, because the code is changed.
So I have made the contact form to send email if there is a space in the name, even two spaces ("John Smith" and "John James Smith") are now acceptable, but if there is a space before the name or after the name ("John Smith " or "  John Smith") it doesn't send. I know that nobody writes his name with a space at the beggining or at the end, but someone might press it accidentally, so how can I correct it? Here is the edited code

```
<?php


function sendemail($toname, $toemail, $fromname, $fromemail, $subject, $message, $type = "plain", $cc = "", $bcc = "") {

    require_once "class.phpmailer.php";

    $mail = new PHPMailer();


        $mail->IsMAIL();




    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->From = $fromemail;
    $mail->FromName = $fromname;
    $mail->AddAddress($toemail, $toname);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($fromemail, $fromname);
    if ($cc) { 
        $cc = explode(", ", $cc);
        foreach ($cc as $ccaddress) {
            $mail->AddCC($ccaddress);
        }
    }
    if ($bcc) {
        $bcc = explode(", ", $bcc);
        foreach ($bcc as $bccaddress) {
            $mail->AddBCC($bccaddress);
        }
    }
    if ($type == "plain") {
        $mail->IsHTML(false);
    } else {
        $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $message;

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $mail->ErrorInfo;
        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
        $mail->ClearReplyTos();
        return false;
    } else {
        $mail->ClearAllRecipients(); 
        $mail->ClearReplyTos();
        return true;
    }

}
}


function descript($text, $striptags = true) {
// Convert problematic ascii characters to their true values
    $search = array("40","41","58","65","66","67","68","69","70",
        "71","72","73","74","75","76","77","78","79","80","81",
        "82","83","84","85","86","87","88","89","90","97","98",
        "99","100","101","102","103","104","105","106","107",
        "108","109","110","111","112","113","114","115","116",
        "117","118","119","120","121","122"
        );
    $replace = array("(",")",":","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h",
        "i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u",
        "v","w","x","y","z","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h",
        "i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u",
        "v","w","x","y","z"
        );
    $entities = count($search);
    for ($i=0; $i < $entities; $i++) {
        $text = preg_replace("#(&\#)(0*".$search[$i]."+);*#si", $replace[$i], $text);
    }
    $text = preg_replace('#(&\#x)([0-9A-F]+);*#si', "", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+[/\"\'\s])(onmouseover|onmousedown|onmouseup|onmouseout|onmousemove|ondblclick|onfocus|onload|xmlns)[^>]*>#iU', ">", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)=([\`\'\"]*)script:#iU', '$1=$2nojscript...', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)=([\`\'\"]*)javascript:#iU', '$1=$2nojavascript...', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)=([\'\"]*)vbscript:#iU', '$1=$2novbscript...', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+)style=([\`\'\"]*).*expression\([^>]*>#iU', "$1>", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+)style=([\`\'\"]*).*behaviour\([^>]*>#iU', "$1>", $text);
    if ($striptags) {
        do {
            $thistext = $text;
            $text = preg_replace('#</*(applet|meta|xml|blink|link|style|script|embed|object|iframe|frame|frameset|ilayer|layer|bgsound|title|base)[^>]*>#i', "", $text);
        } while ($thistext != $text);
    }
    return $text;
}

$name=0;
$telefon=0;
$sender=0;
$syobshtenie=0;
$ename=0;
$etelefon=0;
$esender=0;
$esyobshtenie=0;

if($_POST['name']){
$name = $_POST['name'];
if(eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $sender))
{
$sender="Име";
}
}
else { $name=1; $ename=1; }


if($_POST['sender']){
$sender = $_POST['sender'];
if(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $sender))
{
$sender="Email";
}
}

else { $sender=1; $esender=1; }

if($_POST['telefon']){
$telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
}


if($_POST['zapitvane']){
$zapitvane = $_POST['zapitvane'];
$syobshtenie = "<p>Запитване от ".$_POST['name']."
<br />Email: ".$sender."
<br />Телефон: ".$telefon."</p>".$zapitvane;
}

    else { $syobshtenie=1; $esyobshtenie=1; }


if($name=="Име"){ $ename=1; }
if($telefon=="Телефон"){ $etelefon=1; }
if($sender=="Email"){ $esender=1; }
if($syobshtenie=="Моля, въведете съобщение до нас"){ $esyobshtenie=1; }


if($ename==0 && $esender==0 && $esyobshtenie==0 && $etelefon==0){

sendemail("VillaDes", "info@konsumator.com", "", $sender, $name, $syobshtenie, "", "", "");

echo '
<div class="active-error"" style="margin-top:5px;">Съобщението Ви беше изпратено.<br /><br />Приятен ден!</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("contact").reset();
</script>';
}


else {
echo '
<div class="border-15"></div><div class="active-error"><b>Моля, въведете:</b></div><div class="border-8"></div>';

if($ename==1) { echo '<div class="active-error">Име</div><div class="border-8"></div>'; }
if($esender==1) { echo '<div class="active-error">Е-поща</div><div class="border-8"></div>'; }
if($etelefon==1) { echo '<div class="active-error">Телефон</div><div class="border-8"></div>'; }
if($esyobshtenie==1) { echo '<div class="active-error">Запитване</div>'; }  
}

                echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#close-email").click(function () { $("#mailresult").hide("fast"); } );
                });
                </script>';

?>
```

and this is the problematic part, the name, where something has to be done in order to accept any number and position of spaces or other symbols

```
if($_POST['name']){
$name = $_POST['name'];
if(eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $sender))
{
$sender="Име";
}
}
else { $name=1; $ename=1; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the trim function?

```
   $name = $_POST['name'];
    $name = trim($name); //Removes space from start and end of the string
    ...
```

Comment: whwre should I put it, before or after the if? sorry, don't know a thing about php

Comment: ah nvm, I will reply when I test it

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help